# как измененить цвета раскрывающегося блока аккордеона на jquery?

Tags: jquery, background

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".box1 ul").hide();
$(".box1 h3").click(function(){
    
if(this.style.backgroundColor) this.style.backgroundColor = "";
        else
    this.style.backgroundColor = "#ec6b56";
    
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
    var text = $("span",this).text();
    $("span",this).text(text != "+" ? "+" : "—");
});
});
```

```css
h3{
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #5abae4;
    color: #ffffff;
    font: 700 14px / 40px sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-left: 18px;
}
h3 span {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 12px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

ul li {
    background: #fff url(../images/print_bg.png) center left no-repeat;
    background-position: 18px;
    padding-left: 56px;
    height: 48px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #000000;
    font: 400 14px / 50px sans-serif;
    border: #eae9ee solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box1">
            <h3>Документы и информационные материалы<span class="expand">+</span></h3>
            <ul>
                <li>Приказ о создании 1</li>
                <li>Приказ о создании 1</li>
                <li>Приказ о создании 1</li>
                <li>Приказ о создании 1</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: да, оно, а как обратно? скилл еще слаб(

Comment: Спасибо, получилось, уже исправил.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так?

```
$(".box1 h3").css({"background-color": "yellowgreen"});
```